# Как поменять класс предыдущему элементу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как реализовать смену стиля `<li>` предыдущего, если есть класс "active" у элемента `<a>`?

```
 <li class="ai">
   <a class="active" href="#">
 </li>
 <li class="ai">
   <a href="#">
 </li>
 <li class="ai">
   <a href="#">
 </li>
```

Comment: Какого "предыдущего"? Того, в котором `<a class='active'>`?

Comment: Вы все верно поняли

Comment: @kff Если есть <a class='active'>, то нужно изменить класс li в котором он находится

Comment: Когда должна происходить смена? По клику? `$('a.active').parent().addClass('ai-active');` – так можно добавить класс "ai-parent" родительскому ("предыдущему") элементу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно выбрать все элементы `<a>` с классом `.active`, и их [родителям](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) добавить класс, например, `.ai-active`:

```
$('a.active').parent().addClass('ai-active');
```

```js
$('a.active').parent().addClass('ai-active');
```

```css
.ai{border:1px solid #AAA}
.ai-active {background-color:#F93}
a.active { display:block;width:50px; background-color:#09F; text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="ai">
   <a class="active" href="#">1</a>
 </li>
 <li class="ai">
   <a href="#">2</a>
 </li>
 <li class="ai">
   <a href="#">3</a>
 </li>
```